# python not removing list item for directory list

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to return a list based on a directory listing for sorting.  My problem is that when I do a loop for each file in that list and attempt to remove based on the user inputted extension with `.endswith()` it doesnt seem to update the list correctly (but it does print out "removing file..."). Am I doing something wrong? should I be updating or returning the list (`files`) somewhere I am not?>

Also if I set the dirlist variable `files` as `files=file_list.sort()` it returns none, I have to set `files=sorted(file_list)` ... why is that?

```
import os

class Sort:

dirchoice = os.getcwd()
file_list = list(os.listdir(dirchoice))
files=sorted(file_list)

def file_extension(self):
    if input("Would you like to specify a particular file extension [Y/N]").lower() == ('y' or 'yes'):
        ext=input("filetype>")
        ext = str(ext)
        for file in self.files:
            print(file)
            if not file.endswith(ext):
                self.files.remove(file)
                print("removing " +file+ " from list...")
        return self.files
        print("File Contents:  ")        
        pprint.pprint(self.files)     
        return self.file_extension()
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger? Add breakpoints in your program and find out which line is causing the subject of your bug.

Comment: sorry guys, first post, is that better? I cant even make this work on IDLE, it must be something im missing with loops and lists from a dirlist

Comment: ok I solved it - you cant remove on a list your iterating through already for some reason? so I removed 'file' from 'file_list' and then updated 'files' later.... why is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to your last comment:

it's because the `for` loop retrieves items from the `files` list  in sequence, at the start of each iteration of the loop. It uses a hidden integer index to do this. So if elements are removed during iteration, the index gets "out of sync".

This post contains some more detail: [How to remove list elements in a for loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665591/how-to-remove-list-elements-in-a-for-loop-in-python)

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, is there a similar reason why I couldn't use file_list.sort() but sorted(file_list) was ok?