# Python few elements of the list were skipped while removing them in for loop

Tags: python

I am wondering what is the reason why some elements weren't removed in this program. Could someone provide pointers?

Program:

```
t = ['1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '8', '9', '10']

print len(t)

for x in t:
    if x == '2':
            print x
            t.remove(x)
    else:
        print 'hello: '+str(x)

print t
```

Output on my system:

```
14
hello: 1
2
2
2
2
2
hello: 8
hello: 9
hello: 10
['1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

I am using Python 2.6.2.

Comment: The problem here is that you're modifying the list while iterating over it, which is a no-no.

Comment: Iterate backwards, or read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665591/how-to-remove-list-elements-in-a-for-loop-in-python.

Comment: Are you still wanting to know _why_ the elements are skipped, or have you worked it out now?

Answer (score 3):

Never alter the sequence on which you're iterating.

@cjonhson318's list-comprehension will work fine, or, less efficiently but more closely akin to your code, just loop on a *copy* of the list while you're altering the list itself:

```
for x in list(t):
    if x == '2':
            print x
            t.remove(x)
    else:
        print 'hello: '+str(x)
```

As you see the only change from your code is looping on `list(t)` (a copy of `t`'s initial value) rather than on `t` itself -- this modest change lets you alter `t` itself within the loop to your heart's contents.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I have missed some Python Internals here on how it implemented looping over the list and impact of removal of it's items while looping over it. At this moment, I understand I shouldn't modify the the list while iterating over it. However, if there are any Python Internals concepts in understanding this deeper would be very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bharath, no deep internals involved: very simply, looping on a sequence (or a dict or a set) does NOT imply making a copy of it (which would take time and memory) so you can't modify the structure of the underlying container while you're looping -- if you DO want to modify structure as you loop (and, of course, therefore inevitably accept the time/memory costs thereof), just explicitly take a copy yourself. "Explicit is better than implicit"!-)

Answer (score 1):

Say something like:

```
t = [ i for i in t if i != '2' ]
for item in t:
    print "Hello "+item
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to get functional

```
from operator import ne
from functools import partial

t = ['1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '8', '9', '10']

for n in filter(partial(ne, '2'), t):
    print('hello {}'.format(n))
```

Use the `filter` function to create a new list minus the `2` values.

If the use of `partial` and `operator.ne` was not to your liking, you could use a lambda

```
for n in filter(lambda x: x != '2', t):
    print('hello {}'.format(n))
```