# Python - How to use a function to delete any list element that matches the users input

Tags: python, list, function

Basically I want the user to input a number, that then scans the words in a list that are imported from dictionary.txt. It then deletes any word that's length is equal to the users input and then updates the list outside of the function.

```
def read_and_delete(x):
        count = 0
        i = 0
        for delete in x:
            if x[i] != word_length:
                del x[i]
                i += 1
                return
            elif x[i] == word_length:
                count += 1
                i += 1
                return
            else:
                break
        print(len(list_of_words))

word_length = int(input("Please enter a word length: "))
dictionary = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
list_of_words = [word.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r') for word in dictionary]
read_and_delete(list_of_words)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I want to review the function you already have:

```
def read_and_delete(x):
    count = 0
    i = 0

    # for each word in list, store word in the "delete" variable
    for delete in x:

        # you are iterating over elements, but also using index
        if x[i] != word_length:  # if word not equals length
            del x[i]
            i += 1
            return  # exit from function

        elif x[i] == word_length:  # again, comparing a word and a number
            count += 1
            i += 1
            return  # exit from function
        else:  # never happens, because word is either
               # equal or not, there is no other case
            break  # exit from loop
    # if we actually visited the for loop (the list was not empty),
    # this line would never be executed
    print(len(list_of_words))
```

Next, how to fix it:

1. If you want to iterate over *all* list, you should not use return or break (these are useful in other cases, thought).
2. If you do want to remove elements from a list, you should do that a bit differently: [How to remove list elements in a for loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665591/how-to-remove-list-elements-in-a-for-loop-in-python)
3. To get length of the word (and any other string) you can use `len()`.
4. Also, check the logic of your conditions.

To summarize, here's the fixed function (makes a new list):

```
def read_and_delete(x):
    result = []

    for word in x:
        if len(word) != word_length:
            result.append(word)  # add word to the end of "result"

    print(len(result))
```

As you can see, the loop is pretty simple now. So, you can rewrite it as a list comprehension:

```
# instead of function call
filtered_list = [word for word in list_of_words if len(word) != word_length]
print(len(filtered_list))
```

You can read that as:

```
[word                          # put each "word" into a list
 for word in list_of_words     # get them from "list_of_words"
 if len(word) != word_length]  # leave only those which length != "word_length"
```

**Edit: fixed condition in the function.**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `dictionary.txt` lists one word per line:

```
word_length = int(input("Please enter a word length: "))

with open("dictionary.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as word_list:
    words = [line.strip() for line in word_list if len(line.strip()) != word_length]

print("%i words remain" % len(words))
print(words)
```

The idea is not to make a list and then delete items from it in a separate step, but to filter the items while we are building the list.

Comment: all the words are on individual lines, I should of mentioned that

Comment: So the above should work (In the future, always include a sample of your input in your question. Write the question in such a way that someone with *no context at all* has all the necessary information.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use built-in 'filter' function:

```
ls = ['word1','word','w0']
len_delete = 4
new_ls = filter(lambda x:len(x)!=len_delete,ls)
```

new_ls = ['word1', 'w0']

Comment: Sweet! Oddly, this works in place as well `ls = filter(lambda x:len(x)!=len_delete.ls)` I shall have to have a look at `filter`

Comment: it's not in-place operation, basically you just redeclared variable 'ls'

Comment: `ls = ['word1','word','w0']
    len_delete = 4

    print 'id before: {0}'.format(id(ls))

    ls = filter(lambda x:len(x)!=len_delete,ls)

    print 'id after: {0}'.format(id(ls))`

Comment: Thanks for the proof!

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_and_delete(x):
    resulting_list = []          
    for delete in x:
        if len(delete) == word_length: # len(delete) returns length of element
            continue  # goes to the next element in the list                             
        else:
            resulting_list.append(delete)             
    print(resulting_list)

word_length = int(input("Please enter a word length: "))
dictionary = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
list_of_words = [word.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r') for word in dictionary]
read_and_delete(list_of_words)
```

P.s. study more about how loops work :)

Comment: Why use `enumerate` in this code? Surely `for delete in x` would work.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony you are right. Thanks for the hint. I was re-writing original code and there were 'count' and 'i' variables. I switched it to enumerate and after other changes did not realize that they are unnecessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you come from a C perspective or a similar language:

```
def read_and_delete(x):
    for ix, delete in enumerate(x):
        if len(delete) == word_length:
            del x[ix]

    return x

word_length = int(input("Please enter a word length: "))
dictionary = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
list_of_words = [word.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r') for word in dictionary]
read_and_delete(list_of_words)
print(list_of_words)
```

This newer version of your code will update the list in-place and therefore any change made inside `read_and_delete` for `x`--the passed list to the function, will affect all references of that list including `list_of_words`. This function also returns the affected list, however you can easily remove it because `list_of_words` gets updated by any change made to it inside the function. Of course, there is an easier way to achieve this in Python, for clarity I went with your code so not to puzzle you.

**Edit:** 
Thanks to *@RolfofSaxony* for pointing out the ambiguity in the above code, as I result I've edited this question to address the problem:

```
word_length = int(input("Please enter a word length: "))
dictionary = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
list_of_words = [word.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r') for word in dictionary]

def read_and_delete(x):
    for delete in x[:]:
        if len(delete) == word_length:
            ix = x.index(delete)
            del x[ix]
    return x


read_and_delete(list_of_words)
print(list_of_words)
```

Comment: You're modifying the list while you iterate over it, it will fail! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list

Comment: @ Rolf of Saxony Thanks for pointing that out. I never thought about it. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

My sixpences worth:

```
def read_and_delete(x,word_length):
    x = [elem for elem in x if len(elem) !=word_length]
    return x

a=['123','1234','123','123','abcdef','abc','1234']
a=read_and_delete(a,3)
a
['1234', 'abcdef', '1234']
```

Sorry @Meloman! Just seen your post, which I virtually replicate and with considerably less explanation.