# retrieve in list occurrences from text python

Tags: python

```
Text = input('please enter your text')
l = [str(x) for x in Text.split()]
count = 0
for item in l:
    for i in range(1,len(item)):
        if item[i-1] == item[i]:
            count +=1
    if count <1:
        l.remove(item)
    count = 0
print (l)
```

the goal is : if we have a text : 'baaaaah mooh lpo mpoo' to get a list with elements they have 2 successive same characters, in this case ['baaaaah', 'mooh', 'mpoo' ]

the program is working with the mentioned example

if i use this one it's not working : 'hgj kio mpoo'

thank you

Comment: `[str(x) for x in List.split()]` is the same as doing `List.split()` ;)

Comment: sorry List is a string not a list

Comment: Also, to iterate over characters of a word along with indices of the characters, you should do this : `for index,char in enumerate(word)`

Comment: You should not modify the list which you are iterating.

Comment: @mshsayem could you explain why please ?

Comment: @MSK See the answer.

Comment: @mshsayem OK thank you it's clear :)

Answer (score 1):

(complex)One liner:

```
>>> def successive_items(s):
        return [x for x in s.split() if any(x[i]==x[i-1] for i in range(1,len(x)))]

>>> successive_items('baaaaah mooh lpo mpoo')
['baaaaah', 'mooh', 'mpoo']
>>> successive_items('hgj kio mpoo')
['mpoo']
```

In case of your code, you should not modify the list you are iterating over. Say, for example, lets have an array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Now, if you iterate and remove elements (inside the loop), you would expect `a` to be empty. But let's check out:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for item in a:
        a.remove(item)

>>> a
[2, 4]
```

See? It is not empty. This is better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list#answer-6260097).

Your program is not working for the second case because of list modification. Here is how:

1. Initially your list had `['hgj','kio','mpoo']`.
2. After reading the first element you removed `hgj`. So the list now becomes `['kio','mpoo']`.
3. The loop iterates the 2nd element next, and it gets `mpoo` (in the modified list);
4. `kio` was never read.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
sentence = input("please enter your text")

words = sentence.split()

answers = []
for each_word in words:
    for idx in range(1, len(each_word)):
        if each_word[idx] == each_word[idx-1]:
            answers.append(each_word)
            break

print(answers)
```

In your code, you are iterating over a list and at the same time you are modifying that very same list(by deleting elements from it), for more explanation see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10665602/5341013)

Comment: do you know why my program is not working ?