# How to open file, convert string and write to new file

Tags: python, string, text

I am trying to open a text file, remove certain words that have a ] after them, and then write the new contents to a new file. With the following code, `new_content` contains what I need, and a new file is created, but it's empty. I cannot figure out why. I've tried indenting differently and passing in an encoding type, with no luck. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import glob
import os
import nltk, re, pprint
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
import pandas
import string
import collections

path = "/pathtofiles"

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(file, 'r')
        flines = f.readlines()
        for line in flines: 
            content = line.split() 

            for word in content:
                if word.endswith(']'):
                    content.remove(word)

            new_content = ' '.join(content)

            f2 = open((file.rsplit( ".", 1 )[ 0 ] ) + "_preprocessed.txt", "w")
            f2.write(new_content)
            f.close
```

Comment: `for word in content:
                if word.endswith(']'):
                    content.remove(word)` that's removing while iterating: _bad_

Comment: `f.close` does nothing, and indentation is wrong.

Comment: `if file.endswith(".txt")` is guaranteed to be always true because of the globbing your performed.

Comment: you're not closing `f2` at all

Comment: You should open the file for writing with mode 'a'. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open. Or make a list of words and then use `writelines`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for the comments, I'll work on those. Why is removing while iterating bad?

Comment: Build `new_content` as you iterate through `content` instead of doing remove.

Comment: @Adonis thanks for the help, I'll look in to those. I would like to understand whythis code doesn't work however, as when I originally wrote it for something else it worked perfectly (even if perhaps not the best solution).

Comment: "Worked perfectly", can you tell more? Can you give us the data you are using? Because right now, using "write" mode instead of "append" when opening a file is going to erase what was previously in the file, which at best will result in a file containing one word. Please have a look at how to create a [mcve]

Comment: For remove while iterating, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665591/how-to-remove-list-elements-in-a-for-loop-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work @firefly. Happy to answer questions if you have them.

```
import glob
import os

path = "/pathtofiles"

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            flines = f.readlines()
            new_content = []
            for line in flines: 
                content = line.split() 

                new_content_line = []

                for word in content:
                    if not word.endswith(']'):
                        new_content_line.append(word)

                new_content.append(' '.join(new_content_line))

            f2 = open((file.rsplit( ".", 1 )[ 0 ] ) + "_preprocessed.txt", "w")
            f2.write('\n'.join(new_content))
            f.close
            f2.close
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `mode="w"`?

Comment: works on my machine ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. AFAIK the difference between w and a is simply creating a new file vs appending. OP seemed to indicate wanting a new file each time so `w` makes more sense to me

Comment: Thank you @PeterDolan! I understand what this is doing and why it's better. However the file is still blank for me! I was working on a mac and have tried it on windows too. Is there something else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: So for some reason in the end this worked for some finals but not all...by adding `encoding = 'utf-8'` after `r` and `w` it worked for all files.

Comment: Interesting, maybe there are some weird characters in your files. Glad to hear its working though -- any other questions?