# Sorting a list based on upper and lower case

Tags: python, list, sorting, uppercase, lowercase

I have a list:

```
List1 = ['name','is','JOHN','My']
```

I want to append the pronoun as the first item in a new list and append the names at last. Other items should be in the middle and their positions can change.

So far I have written:

```
my_list = ['name','is','JOHN','My']

new_list = []

for i in my_list:
  if i.isupper():
    my_list.remove(i)
  new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

Here, I can't check if an item is completely upper case or only its first letter is upper case.

Output I get:

```
['name','is','JOHN','My']
```

Output I want:

```
['My','name','is','JOHN']
```

or:

```
['My','is','name','JOHN']
```

**EDIT:** I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665591/how-to-remove-list-elements-in-a-for-loop-in-python) post and it doesn’t have answers to my question.

Comment: You should not modify a list that you're iterating over.

Comment: on what condition are you  sorting the list?

Comment: `[t[1] for t in sorted((0 if s.istitle() else 2 if s.isupper() else 1, s) for s in List1)]` (and no I am not going to post it as an answer because it is not maintainable code even though it works...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i.isupper()` will tell you if it's all uppercase.

To test if just the first character is uppercase and the rest lowercase, you can use `i.istitle()`

To make your final result, you can append to different lists based on the conditions.

```
all_cap = []
init_cap = []
non_cap = []

for i in my_list:
    if i.isupper():
        all_cap.append(i)
    elif i.istitle():
        init_cap.append(i)
    else: 
        non_cap.append(i)

new_list = init_cap + non_cap + all_cap
print(new_list)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/No1FpP)

Comment: `istitle` method?

Comment: That's even better

Comment: @Barmar I am getting this as the output: `['John', 'My', 'name', 'is']`

Comment: I just ran it and get `['My', 'name', 'is', 'JOHN']`

Comment: You'll get that output if the input contains `John` instead of `JOHN`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I got it. I mistakenly typed John.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
s = ['name', 'is', 'JOHN', 'My']

pronoun = ''
name = ''
for i in s:
    if i.isupper():
        name = i
    if i.istitle():
        pronoun = i

result = [pronoun, s[0], s[1], name]

print(result)
```

Comment: I think you should write this as a comment

Comment: i can't leave comments :(

Comment: But you did comment above!

Comment: sorry, you are right. specifically, i cannot comment on other people's answers. i've edited my response with actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't @ me pls XD. Try this.

```
my_list = ['name','is','JOHN','My']
            
new_list = ['']

for i in range(len(my_list)):
  if my_list[i][0].isupper() and my_list[i][1].islower():
    new_list[0] = my_list[i]
  elif my_list[i].islower():
    new_list.append(my_list[i])
  elif my_list[i].isupper():
      new_list.append(my_list[i])
    
print(new_list)
```

Comment: You do the same thing in the `islower()` and `isupper()` cases. That won't reorder them.

Comment: Did you try running it? XD ... just taking advantage of how code is read and implemented based on sequence...but then again, who am I to say...i'm still new to programming XD

Comment: Change the order of the input to `['JOHN','name','is','My']` and the result is `['My', 'JOHN', 'name', 'is']`

Comment: All your code does is put the word with initial capital first, everything else is kept in the original order.

Comment: You don't put the all-uppercase word last.

Comment: but .append() DOES put the value in the last slot...doesn't it? which is why all upper-case word is in the last line of the code...it does re-order the sequence based on the problem presented

Comment: You're putting both `islower()` and `isupper()` in the last slot.

Comment: You're not processing all the `islower()` first, you're processing them in the order that they appear in the input list.

Comment: Try it with the altered input and you'll see.