# why isn't this Python program giving desirable result?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have started learning Python. So I tried to run the following program:

```
nom = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for x in nom:
    print(nom)
    nom.pop(1)
print(nom)
```

I expected to get 1 printed at the end , but what I got is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 5, 6]
```

As the loop seems interrupted in midway. Why is that? please explain.

Comment: What's the error you get when the loop gets interrupted?

Comment: You should not modify a list as you are iterating over it. Please see the linked questions with more detailed explanations.

Comment: In addition to the linked ones above, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665591/how-to-remove-list-elements-in-a-for-loop-in-python

Comment: @CoryKramer Thank you very much. This line cleared my confusion "You should not modify a list as you are iterating over it". I executed the program by iterating over other list.