# Remove item from one list if NOT in another list?

Tags: python

This problem sounds very simple and probably has a very easy solution. However, nothing I have tried works.

The file I am importing, 'bedwars.csv', has 29 rows. Each (comma-separated) row consists of a player and their point value: 'Player, Points'.

I have a list of 16 players, 'samplePlayers.csv', all of whom are also in 'bedwars.csv'. I am trying to remove the players that are NOT in 'sampleplayers.csv' from 'bedwars.csv'. FWIW the players in 'samplePlayers.csv' ae just the first 16 players in 'bedwars.csv'.

My attempt is below.

```
import pandas as pd    

playing = pd.read_csv('samplePlayers.csv') # test data

# imports all past game data
bedwars = pd.read_csv('bedwars.csv')
bedwars.columns = ['Players', 'Points']
players = list(bedwars.Players)
points = list(bedwars.Points)
bedwarsPoints = list(zip(players, points))
print(bedwarsPoints)

for i in bedwarsPoints:
    if i not in playing:
        bedwarsPoints.remove(i)
print(bedwarsPoints)
```

Outputs the following:

```
[('Star_Dragon4', 40.88), ('LethalPilot', 32.18625), ('macrocosms', 27.4), ('mrjad333', 25.82142857), ('IceKing12323', 22.51666667), ('AllieThaDon', 20.568), ('SuperToad916', 18.675), ('odsstel', 18.04285714), ('NautilusReign', 17.6), ('14ham', 16.39), ('Hunter13004', 15.72), ('sapphronn', 15.44), ('SerRonanIrwin', 14.23333333), ('LightningLucario', 14.062), ('Dispuesto', 13.565), ('KirynMissy', 13.12285714), ('Abach6', 12.68857143), ('lurchlurger', 11.78), ('Labmonjo1210', 10.78), ('humilau', 9.65125), ('BYTECH', 9.57), ('de_eh', 9.3), ('cowDude12345', 8.65), ('Menderlovemybug', 8.5), ('tenparks', 8.366666667), ('TheUW', 6.8), ('QuinnQuimby', 5.2), ('stealthguy11', 4.05), ('Buck274', 0.0)]
[('LethalPilot', 32.18625), ('mrjad333', 25.82142857), ('AllieThaDon', 20.568), ('odsstel', 18.04285714), ('14ham', 16.39), ('sapphronn', 15.44), ('LightningLucario', 14.062), ('KirynMissy', 13.12285714), ('lurchlurger', 11.78), ('humilau', 9.65125), ('de_eh', 9.3), ('Menderlovemybug', 8.5), ('TheUW', 6.8), ('stealthguy11', 4.05)]
```

The first being an array of length 29 (good), the array from 'samplePlayers.csv'. The second, however, consists of the mangled remnants of the attempted removal. I noticed that the "for" loop has only been removing every other value.

Please let me know if any more clarification is needed and I will respond. Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: By the way, one should not remove an item from a list in a `for` loop over the list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665591/how-to-remove-list-elements-in-a-for-loop-in-python

Comment: You should simply make a new list: `bedwarsPoints = [i for i in bedwarsPoints if i in playing]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `playing` is a list of strings corresponding to player names:

```py
bedwarsPoints = [i for i in bedwarsPoints if i[0] in playing]
```